# Why krb5 function does not get resolved when we include "krb5.h"?

Tags: c, gcc

When I include "stdio.h" and try to use "printf" it works fine.
In the same way when I use "krb5.h", its function "krb5_get_init_creds_password" does not get resolved by its own.

Error faced :
bash-4.1$ gcc krb.c
krb.c: In function ‘main’:
krb.c:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
/tmp/ccTK4DJM.o: In function `main':
krb.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to`krb5_get_init_creds_password'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

**I had to compile using -lkrb5 which resolved the issue.**

**Can someone let me know why do I need to use gcc option "-lkrb5" to get that krb5 function resolved ?**
I am using C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: My question is different @Olaf

Comment: It is apparently not! Read the answers and understand!

Answer (score 2):

The header file you include only contains the *declaration* of the function, the actual function *definition* (the implementation) is in the actual *library* (usually a file named (using your example) `libkrb5.a` or `libkrb5.so`).

The option you pass to the linker is `-l` (lower-case L) which tells the linker to find and use whatever library you pass as argument to the `-l` option.

---

If you have create programs consisting of multiple source files yourself, then this should not have been much of a surprise really. If you have two source files `a.c` and `b.c`, where in `a.c` you call a function defined in `b.c` you need to *declare* the function for it to be available in `a.c`. And then when you link the executable program you need to link with the object file created by `b.c` to be able to find the definition.

Using a library is really not much different from that.

Comment: is there any way I come to know in advance if the definition is there or not ?

Comment: @Mayank For C there are seldom any "header only" libraries. And you find out if it is by reading the documentation.